# log4j file appender do not normal

Tags: java, log4j, fileappender

My `log4j.properties` is:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=../logs/xrzgather.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=100
```

I have many tomcat server run the application,and all of them run normal with the right log but one of them do not normal,it generate the log file:

```
    xrzgather.log  182M  
    xrzgather.log.19  254M  
    xrzgather.log.45  48.6M  
    xrzgather.log.50  400M  
    xrzgather.log.90  20.8M  
    xrzgather.log.92  66.3M  
    xrzgather.log.99  11.9M
```

Has anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Try debugging log4j configuration with `log4j.debug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason..
I config a Context element in %tomcat_home%\conf\Server.xml like this:

```
<Context path="xrz-gather" docBase="xrz-gather-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT" />
```

if I remove this,log will be normal.